# Randomly generate network with specified clustering coefficient

Tags: r, igraph

In the past I have used `igraph` to generate small world networks with a specified rewiring probability `p`, which is especially easy because it's an argument in the `sample_smallworld` function. For instance:

```
myNetwork <- sample_smallworld(dim = 1, size = 10, nei = 2, p = 0.25)
plot(myNetwork, layout = layout_in_circle)
```

[image]

I'd now like to generate small world networks with a specified clustering coefficient. I'm new to `igraph` and this seems like a functionality that it would have, but after some searching I've only found ways to calculate the coefficient from pre-existing networks, rather than a way to use it as a parameter for generating the network itself.

*What's the best way to generate networks with a specified clustering coefficient ?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are okay with a few conditions, then it is possible to get a sort of hacky approximation using `sna::rguman()`. The conditions are: (1) using global transitivity (maybe you could work with it and modify); (2) using undirected graphs; (3) using large size graphs if using small values of transitivity, or use larger values of transitivity for small size graphs. Also, give up the `sample_smallworld()` algorithm. If that's ok this might get you where you want to go:

```r
library(sna)
library(igraph)

sample_cluster <- function(nv = 150, clustering_coef = 0.5, thres = 0.05) {
  g <- sna::rguman(1, nv, mut = clustering_coef, asym = 0, null = 1 - clustering_coef) %>% 
    graph_from_adjacency_matrix(mode = "undirected")

  while (!(transitivity(g) >= clustering_coef-thres & transitivity(g) <= clustering_coef+thres)) {
    g <- sna::rguman(1, nv, mut = clustering_coef, asym = 0, null = 1 - clustering_coef) %>% 
      graph_from_adjacency_matrix(mode = "undirected")
  }

  return(g)

} 


sample_cluster(15, clustering_coef = 0.2, thres = 0.001) %>% transitivity()
#> [1] 0.2

sample_cluster(200, clustering_coef = 0.01, thres = 0.001) %>% transitivity()
#> [1] 0.009009009

sample_cluster(200, clustering_coef = 0.2, thres = 0.001) %>% transitivity()
#> [1] 0.2007628

sample_cluster(20, clustering_coef = 0.7, thres = 0.001) %>% transitivity()
#> [1] 0.7007168
```

<sup>Created on 2020-03-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Not fancy, not sophisticated, but might do the trick!

Answer (score 0):

As far I understand, you cannot specify the clustering coefficient (or transitivity, as it is named in the `igraph` package) because it is conditional on the parameters you specify.

Why? `sample_smallworld` generates a graph according to the Watts-Strogatz Model, as explained in the [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/igraph/versions/1.2.4.2/topics/sample_smallworld). Check out the maths of the model on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watts%E2%80%93Strogatz_model). The Watts-Strogatz model has three parameters:

1. Number of nodes (`size` parameter in the `sample_smallworld` method, *N* in the wikipedia article);
2. Average number of links per node (`nei` parameter, *K* on wikipedia);
3. Probability of connecting random pair of nodes, for each link in the graph, via "rewiring" (`p` parameter, *beta* on Wikipedia).

Have a look at Wikipedia (section "Clustering coefficient") to understand how the clustering coefficient can be computed from these parameters.

More empirically, if you play around with the parameters in your model, you can see how they affect the clustering coefficient with the `transitivity` command.

```
# clustering coefficient in your data:

myNetwork <- sample_smallworld(dim = 1, size = 10, nei = 2, p = 0.25)
transitivity(myNetwork)
[1] 0.3870968
```

```
# Varying average links/node:

for(i in 1:5) {
  set.seed(1) # use this to get the same results
  myNetwork <- sample_smallworld(dim = 1, size = 10, nei = i, p = 0.25)
  print(transitivity(myNetwork, type="global"))
}

[1] 0
[1] 0.2380952
[1] 0.6
[1] 0.8723404
[1] 1
```

```
# Varying rewiring probability:

for(i in c(0.05, 0.1, 0.2, 0.5, 1)) {
  set.seed(1)
  myNetwork <- sample_smallworld(dim = 1, size = 10, nei = 2, p = i)
  print(transitivity(myNetwork, type="global"))
}
[1] 0.483871
[1] 0.4615385
[1] 0.328125
[1] 0.3802817
[1] 0.4347826
```